# Return the results of running a program in realtime using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bash, shell

Is there a way to run a program (for example: tcpdump) and every time it shows something through the console, from nodejs capture it and return the result to print in an html? no need to save it, keep it in real time.

My idea is that a program can be executed and while it is running and showing things in the console, they can be sent to the html where you can progressively see all the results of the program's execution.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I hope "print in an html" means "write the output to a html file"?

Comment: exactly, sorry for my bad expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using socket io is a good solution,
check there get [started tutorial](https://socket.io/get-started/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything like "capturing output" in Node.js. You can use the heredoc available in almost every shell. The heredoc, in the most basic sense, redirects the output of a command to a file. In your example, if you use `tcpdump`, here's what you'd do:

```sh
$ tcpdump [options] >> file.html
```

- The >> heredoc operator appends to a file(create if doesn't exist). This means if you already have some content in file.html, the content will still be there, and the output will be appended to the end of the file.
- The > heredoc writes to a file(also, create if doesn't exist). So, if you have some content in file.html, that will be overwritten with the new content.